# How to avoid the error : There have been too many calls from this ad-account. Wait a bit and try again. For more info,

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm using the Facebook Marketing API to generate a list of all ads, ad names, objectives, and impressions for each day, given a list of ad set ids.
(For those of you who don't know the hierarchy, each campaign has ad sets...each ad set has ads...)

The problem is that I'm apparently making too many calls. What's the best way to optimize this to a minimum number of calls?

```
import requests
import datetime

ad_account_id = 'act_11111'
access_token = 'ABC'
app_secret='secret'
ad_set_ids=['one', 'two']


fields = 'id,name,campaign_id'

# Set up start and end dates for impressions data
start_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 30)

# Initialize variables for pagination and cursor
has_next_page = True
cursor = ''
callnumber=0

while has_next_page:
    # Make an API call to the ad sets endpoint to get the ads for each ad set
    ad_set_request = requests.get(f'https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/?ids={",".join(ad_set_ids)}&fields=ads{{id}}&access_token={access_token}&after={cursor}')

    ad_set_response = ad_set_request.json()

    # Get the ad IDs for each ad set
    ad_ids = []
    for ad_set_id in ad_set_response.keys():
        if 'ads' in ad_set_response[ad_set_id]:
            for ad in ad_set_response[ad_set_id]['ads']['data']:
                ad_ids.append(ad['id'])

    # Make an API call to the ads endpoint to get the ad details
    ad_request = requests.get(f'https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/?ids={",".join(ad_ids)}&fields={fields}&access_token={access_token}&after={cursor}')
    ad_response = ad_request.json()

    # Loop through each ad and print the details
    for ad_id in ad_response.keys():
        # Get the campaign ID from the ad object
        campaign_id = ad_response[ad_id]['campaign_id']

        # Make an API call to the insights edge to get the impressions data for the ad
        insights_request = requests.get(f'https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{ad_id}/insights?metric=impressions&access_token={access_token}&time_range={{"since":"{start_date.date()}","until":"{end_date.date()}"}}')
        insights_response = insights_request.json()
        print(insights_response)


        # Check if there is data for the impressions metric and print the ad details grouped by day
        if 'data' in insights_response and len(insights_response['data']) > 0:
            for data in insights_response['data']:
                for value in data['values']:
                    day = datetime.datetime.strptime(data['time_range']['date_start'], '%Y-%m-%d')
                    impressions = value['value']
                    print(f"Ad ID: {ad_id}")
                    print(f"Ad Name: {ad_response[ad_id]['name']}")
                    print(f"Objective: {get_campaign_objective(campaign_id)}")
                    print(f"Day: {day.date()}")
                    print(f"Impressions: {impressions}")
                    print("")

    # Check if there are more pages of data to retrieve
    if 'paging' in ad_response and 'next' in ad_response['paging']:
        cursor = ad_response['paging']['cursors']['after']
    else:
        has_next_page = False

def get_campaign_objective(campaign_id):
    # Make an API call to the campaign endpoint to get the objective
    campaign_request = requests.get(f'https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{campaign_id}?fields=objective&access_token={access_token}')
    campaign_response = campaign_request.json()
    return campaign_response['objective']
```

Answer (score 2):

you probably just need to add a delay beetween each calls so the server doesn't block you, because of how ddos protection is made. just add time.sleep(1) or 2